# React css modules - Applying styles to native html tags

Tags: css, reactjs

This is pretty straightforward. Let's say I have some `NavBar` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './NavBar.module.css';

export default function NavBar() {
    return(
    <nav className={styles.nav}>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    );
}
```

And now I have a `NavBar.module.css` file:

```
.nav {
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6dd3d6;
}
```

But since I am using the semantic  tag and the benefit of using css-modules is that they cannot cause name interference,
is it somehow possible to directly style the `nav` without having to pass the `styles` class?

Like

```
import styles from './NavBar.module.css';

export default function NavBar() {
    return(
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    );
}
```

with

```
 nav {
        display: flex;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #6dd3d6;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could do something like.

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './NavBar.module.css';

export default function NavBar() {
    return(
    <div className={styles.nav_container}>
      <nav>
          <ul>
              <li>Item 1</li>
              <li>Item 2</li>
              <li>Item 3</li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    );
}
```

in your css module file (NavBar.module.css) you could do

```
.nav_container nav {
      display: flex;
      padding: 20px;
      background: #6dd3d6; 
 }
.nav_container ul{
    /* for example */
    list-style: none;
}

.nav_container li{
      /* for example */
      font-size: large;
}
```

although you'll write nav_container many times in the css file it's more manageable and copy-able, than putting className on each jsx tag.

of course instead of the extra div you can do

```
<nav className={styles.nav}>
   <ul>
       <li>Item 1</li>
       <li>Item 2</li>
       <li>Item 3</li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

and the css module file

```
.nav{
        display: flex;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #6dd3d6;
}

.nav ul{

}

.nav li{

}
```

Comment: Can PostCSS nesting help here?

Comment: @EricBurel I believe it can. it will remove the need to write ".nav_container" or ".nav" many times. SASS nesting will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want style the nav without passing style then you can directly import the css file. Just Like:

```
import './main.css';

// In main.css file you can-> :
nav, .navbar-classname {
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6dd3d6;
}
```

Comment: yeah but I thought if I do that I don't use modules and then if I declare nav somewhere else, those two styles with interfere, right?

Comment: You won't benefit from scoping in most frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to directly inline-styling the HTML tags in React?
yes you can!
you can do it like this

```
<nav style={{"display": "flex", "padding":"20px", "background: #6dd3d6"}}></nav>
```

there's a cleaner way though, if you want to write your style directly in the file without importing any style modules, you might want to check the **styled components** library, they give you the ability to write a styled container directly, for example:

```
const StyledNav = styled.nav`
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6dd3d6;
`

export default function NavBar() {
    return(
    <StyledNav>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </StyledNav>
    );
}
```

but, that introduces a dependency to your project, you can choose from those two, hope they help :D

Comment: I edited my code to make it more clear. Right now I have to pass the "nav" as style, even tho I am styling the nav..like is there a way to omit that. And I have read about styled components, but yeah then I have a nother dependency :S